# Android : Listview First button selected error

Tags: android, listview

When listview Start i found First button was selected ?
i try make on click button event with listview but i don't know the reason ! how i can make it default like all buttons in list ?
take a look about image please.

[image: android image button]

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row = convertView;
    final ContactHolder contactHolder;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        contactHolder = new ContactHolder();
        contactHolder.tx_id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.usersName2);
        contactHolder.tx_id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.usersName2);
        contactHolder.loadId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.loadMoreID);
        contactHolder.tx_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.usersName);
        contactHolder.image_tx = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.usersPic);
        contactHolder.sug_add = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.sug_id);

        row.setTag(contactHolder);


    } else {
        contactHolder = (ContactHolder) row.getTag();

    }
    final Contacts_Sug contacts = (Contacts_Sug) this.getItem(position);
    contactHolder.image_tx.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    contactHolder.tx_id.setText(contacts.getId());
    contactHolder.tx_name.setText(contacts.getName());
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(contacts.getImage(), contactHolder.image_tx);

    contactHolder.tx_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            contacts.setSelectedPosition(position); //Set position here
            contactHolder.sug_add.setText("Selected");
        }


    });
    if(contacts.getSelectedPosition() == position){
        contactHolder.sug_add.setText("Selected");
    } else{
        contactHolder.sug_add.setText("Follow");

    }

    return row;
}


public class ContactHolder {
    TextView tx_id, tx_name,loadId;
    ImageView image_tx;
    public Button sug_add;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because by default, the value of `selectedPos`is "0".

Change your `Contacts_Sug` class to have  the `selectedPos` member variable initialized to -1.

```
private int selectedPos = -1;
```

Comment: thank you sir agian for your perfect answer and time  :)